# Possible to use AutoMapper to map objects nested in List of object

Tags: automapper

`public class Site {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SiteModules> SiteModules{ get; set; }
    }
    public class SiteModules{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Modules modules{ get; set; }
    }
    public class SiteDto{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Modules> Modules{ get; set; }
    }`

I want to create a SiteDto which contains List of Modules instead of SiteModules. Can it be possible with Automapper. I am in great need of this. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Site, SiteDto>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Modules, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom
        (
            src => src.SiteModules.Select(x => x.modules).ToList()
        ));
```

A very simple answer :)